# How can I make sure the problem I want to ask has not been presented before?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, asking-questions, search

e.g. I have a question on proving an inequality statement. If I google it Google will not recognize it and if I use Math StackExchange'search engine, it will not respond. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, you can post your question here. If it has been asked before perhaps someone here remembers it and will link you to it.

Comment: I wouldn't sweat it too much if you make an effort to see if it's been asked before.  But I'm new here and might not represent the general consensus.

Comment: Don't worry about asking something which already had been answered. There are three possibilities: 1) It already had been answered and someone notices: In this case, your question will be linked to the one which already had been answered. 2) It already had been answered and no one notices. Then we will try to answer your question. 3) Your question is new: Then we will try to answer. You see: You will receive help in any case :)

Comment: It seems that you have made a good faith effort to find a previously asked question (this is always a good idea to reduce the amount of duplicate posts on the site). Since you have done that, follow sranthrop's suggestion.

Comment: Additional advice: Check also the list of question which is generated while you type the questions and list of related questions which appears after you post it. The software often does quite a good job in finding related questions if you choose good title and appropriate tags.

Comment: The important thing is to try: most of the time you'll find duplicates after a search or two, if they exist.

Comment: Searching for stuff is problematic at times. I often can't find (easily) stuff I know I have written/answered. A little persistence helps.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you did your part, so feel free to add it.

In fact, to make it easier for folks to find it in the future, you can add statements like

I tried googling for "keywords", but could not find it.

(i.e. add some keywords to your question for easier searching in the future).